# `bitpacked` records on the little-endian machine issue

Tags: delphi, endianness, lazarus, freepascal, bit-fields

I'm trying to use FreePascal on **little-endian machine** to read and interpret data from integrated circuit. The data essentially consists tightly bitpacked (mostly) **big-endian** integer numbers, some of them (a lot, actually) are **not aligned to byte boundary**. So, I've tried to employ FPC's `bitpacked` records for that and found myself in the deep deep trouble.

The first structure I'm trying to read has the following format:

```
{$BITPACKING ON}  
type
  THeader = bitpacked record
    Magic: Byte;        // format id, 8 bits
    _Type: $000..$FFF;  // type specifier, 12 bits
    Version: Word;      // data revision, 16 bits
    Flags: $0..$F       // attributes, 4 bits
  end;
```

And here is a reading code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  F: File;
  Header: THeader;
begin
  Writeln(SizeOf(Header), #9, BitSizeOf(Header));   // reports correctly

  Writeln('SizeOf(Header._Type) = ', SizeOf(Header._Type));       // correctly reports 2 bytes
  Writeln('BitSizeOf(Header._Type) = ', BitSizeOf(Header._Type)); // correctly reports 12 bits

  AssignFile(F, 'D:\3fd8.dat');
  FileMode := fmOpenRead;
  Reset(F, SizeOf(Byte));
  BlockRead(F, Header, SizeOf(Header));

  { data is incorrect beyond this point already }

  //Header._Type := BEtoN(Header._Type);

  Writeln(IntToHex(Header.Magic, SizeOf(Header.Magic) * 2));
  Writeln(IntToHex(BEtoN(Header._Type), SizeOf(Header._Type) * 2));
  Writeln(BEtoN(Header.Version));
end;
```

But the code is printing totally wrong data.

Here is the data and the interpretation done manually:

```
0000000000: F1 55 BE 3F 0A ...
Magic = F1
_Type = 55B
Version = E3F0
Flags = A
```

But FPC sees the data in severely different and incorrect way. Looks like a nibbles (and bits) belonging to field are not contiguous due to little-endianess of host machine (eg: nibble `B` normally should belong to `_Type` field and nibble `E` - to `Version`). Here is a Watches window from Lazarus:

[image]

Please advice what I should do with such behaviour. Is this **non-contiguous bitfield** issue a bug of FPC? Any workarounds possible?

Comment: Added `[delphi]` tag to attract more audience and per chance some clever solutions.

Comment: You will have to decode the header yourself. First take care that the 5 bytes are in the correct order for your endianness and then decode those bytes by shifting and masking. Do not use the bitpacked record.

Comment: Did you set $BITPACKED, or don't you have to (e.g. on a Mac)?

Comment: @Rudy, thanks for suggestion, but looks like `$BITPACKING ON` is in effect already from `bitpacked` keyword. Anyways, adding directive gives me the same non-contiguous result as above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling arbitrary bit length data in Delphi?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26875472/2626313)

Comment: As I said, such bitpacking combined with endianness is problematic in languages like C and C++ too, so I suggest you really use shifts and masks on your bytes and forget about bitpacked records altogether.

Comment: your bits are continuous; the problem wrong nibble order. I don't think it is a FPC bug.

Comment: This has nothing at all to do with Delphi. It's an fpc question. And bitfields are a minefield. Mask and shift.

Comment: @David: I agree. The Delphi tag should be removed and bitfields are mine fields, indeed.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. None of the other questions asks about the FPC `bitpacked` keyword and what that means for a sequence of bytes.

Comment: I really object to your edits. You wouldn't be impressed if I wrote some Delphi code to solve your problem. Perhaps you don't understand what the delphi tag means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bytes

```
F1 55 BE 3F 0A
```

have the following consecutive nibbles (lower nibble before higher nibble):

```
1 F 5 5 E B F 3 A 0
```

If you group these into 2, 3, 4 and 1 nibbles respectively, you get:

```
 1 F     --> $F1    
 5 5 E   --> $E55   // highest nibble last, so E is highest.
 B F 3 A --> $A3FB  // same again: A is highest nibble
 0       --> $0
```

which corresponds to the result you see in the Watch window, and not what you decoded manually.

Now, if the data is big-endian, then you'll have to decode manually using shifts and masking:

```
X.Magic := bytes[0];
X._Type := (bytes[1] shl 4) or (bytes[2] shr 4);
X.Version := ((bytes[2] and $0F) shl 12) or 
             (bytes[3] shl 4) or 
             (bytes[4] shr 4);
X.Flags := bytes[4] and $0F;
```

Comment: I think you nailed it, he expects bigendian, but the result is little endian.

Comment: Sadly, 99% of information on the subject comes from independent researchers and all of them are describing protocol *as seen on hex dump*. E.g. there is no known `_Type = $E55` while there is distinct group in `$54A..$55F` range.

Comment: Well, as seen on the hexdump, the result should be like above, and not what you think it should be, Now, if this is big-endian, you'll have to reverse the data before you use it. Since this is not just a bytewise reversal, and if you really want the data as you decode it, you'll have to use manual shifts and masking, as I said a few times before. But FPC decodes this fully correctly for little-endian, so don't blame FPC. Blame yourself for not properly decoding this first.

Answer (score 1):

I use this function to convert from IEEE format to FPC single:

```
Type MyReal = Array [1..4] of Byte;

function IeeeToSingle (src:MyReal):Single;
      var x:MyReal; 
          s:single absolute x;
          man:word; 
          exp:word;
          ca:single; 
          cb:cardinal absolute ca; // 4 byte unsigned long int
      begin
        x:=src;
        ca:=s;
        if cb>0 then begin                // not zero
            man := cb shr 16;
            exp := (man and $ff00) - $0200;
            if ((exp and  $8000) <> (man and $8000)) then
              MsToIeee := -1; // exponent overflow
            man := (man and  $7f) or ((man shl 8) and  $8000);// move sign
            man := man or (exp  shr  1);
            cb := (cb and  $ffff) or (Cardinal(man)  shl 16);
          end;
          IeeeToSingle := ca;
      end;
```