# Delphi: how to read X bits from TBytes?

Tags: delphi, bit-manipulation, byte, arrays

I've faced with the problem related to reading random number of bits from TBytes. Firstly I followed an advice from this question (the answer about using ubitstream.pas unit): [Handling arbitrary bit length data in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889746/handling-arbitrary-bit-length-data-in-delphi)
My example:
binaryfeed (TBytes) = (255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 132, 1, 112, 128, 128, 130, 81);

1. I read 8 bits and get 255 - ok. Position is 8.
2. I read another 24 bits and get 0 - ok. Position is 32.
3. I read another 24 bits and get 393216 instead of 6. Position is 56.

393216 is 0000 0000 0000 0110 **0000 0000 0000 0000**

I can understand why it happend but I can't figure out how to truncate these extra zero bits. Any ideas?

Comment: This "random number of bits", is it always a multiple of 8 bits? If so, then you can read bytes. If this is big-endian, then multiple bytes are combined to integers by something like: `value := nextByte + value * 256; numBits :=  numBits - 8;`repeatedly, until you have your number of bits.

Comment: If it is really 'bit access' you're looking for (which it doesn't look like it does, see @DavidHeffernan's answer), you should have a look at Delphi's TBits class in System.Classes.pas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

```
00000110 00000000 00000000
```

is 393216. Reverse the three bytes and you have

```
00000000 00000000 00000110
```

which is 6.

The code that you are using is little endian, but you are hoping for big endian behaviour. You will need to change your code to account for this mismatch.

From what we have seen in the question though, you are always reading entire bytes and so there is no need for the complexity of the code you are using. You can operate at the byte level. Obviously you will still need to account for endianness correctly but that is not very challenging.

Comment: >> From what we have seen in the question though, you are always reading entire bytes and so there is no need for the complexity of the code you are using.

I need to support reading for example 3 bits.

Comment: OK fine, that wasn't clear from the question because you always read bits in multiples of 8. The point remains that endianness is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First think of your container. If you read bytes into a 32bit integer, you should use shr/shl to move the bits into place.
its not uncommon to shl left-most bits you dont want out of the 32bit range, then shr the rest X number of positions to get the bytevalues (or word, or whatever size you need).

```
var
  value: integer;
begin
  value := (Readint32FromBuffer shl 8) shr 8;
  writeln(value.tostring);
end;
```

In the above code, we dont want the first 8 bits to be included so we shift the whole thing 8 bits to the left, then 8 bits back. This zeroes out the bits when they move "off the edge" of the container.

Use SHL and SHR to move bits/bytes around inside your variable(s). But remember the size of the container. Word (16 bits), Integer (32 bits) etc.

You can also use AND and OR masks to achieve some of the same, although SHL and SHR are typically faster for variables with the same size as a CPU register (32 bit or 64 bit).